# How to Add SerializationBinder to Remoting (or change type on Deserializing)?

Tags: c#, remoting

Is it possible, and how to apply Serialization Binder to remoting?
Or Change the type from 1 to another assembly?

Thank you!

Comment: I have been trying to find a way to add such serialization binder as a default for remoting, but it seems to be difficult to find .. That's why I am asking here

Comment: Frankly, when this is a concern, my usual approach is "send either a string or byte[], and use a serializer that isn't type-based": any of JavaScriptSerializer, XmlSerializer, protobuf-net, DataContractSerializer, JSON.Net etc. Then each end uses the type representation that it wants to.

Comment: I've just tried looking at this and couldn't find an (obvious) way to create a provider to create a sink to add a filter to set the binder (or whichever steps I missed). I eventually changed tact and did an explicit conversion to a serializable structure in the public assembly.